# google chrome extension open new tab on startup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to know if there's a way to open a website on a new tab when chrome is launched through the service-worker on manifest version 3.

What I tried

```
   // background.js
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.create({url:"https://www.google.com/"});
 })

"manifest_version": 3,
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"permissions": ["storage","activeTab", "scripting", "tabs", "runtime"],
```

Comment: `website.html` is not a valid URL. Use something like `https://www.example.com/`

Comment: It was meant as an example, the problem still stands.

Comment: i got an error "Uncaught (in promise) Error: No current window"

Comment: Try `chrome.windows.create` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** The only way I found so far is by opening the options page. From there, you can dispatch elsewhere.

## The problem: Background page is now a Service Worker

With Manifest v3, the background page is not a "page" any more. It's a service worker that can execute JS, but it has no access to UI-specific elements.

Therefore, chrome.tabs.create(), chrome.windows.create() and the like don't work. We only have access to chrome.runtime.

## Open the options page the only way to open a new tab

You can explore the [chrome.runtime API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-openOptionsPage). I found only one method that opens a new tab: chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage(). For this to work, you need to define an option page in your manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  ...
  "options_ui": {
      "open_in_tab": true,
      "page": "options.html"
  },
}
```

Note that the options page must be bundled with your extension. But if you open it in a tab, you can perform a redirect to wherever you want to be.

Finally, you can use JS on the options page to redirect to any other page, including absolute URLs:

```
window.open("https://www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

## What about different destination pages?

There can only be one options page. But chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage() can take a callback function as an argument, which you can use on the options page to figure out the final destination page.